# Relativistic speed of two elastically colliding particles

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, energy-conservation

In section **16-4 Relativistic mass** of *The Feynman Lectures on Physics* [relativistic mass](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F2)  is discussed with an example of a collision between two equal mass particles.

Frames:

- *Observer 1*: stationary. Collision represented by [16-2](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F2)(b).
- *Observer 2*: moving with the same horizontal velocity as *particle 1*'s. Collision represented by [16-3](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F3)(a).

For *Observer 2*, [16-3](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html#Ch16-F3)(a) shows that the vertical speed for *particle 1* is $w$, while the vertical speed or $u \tan \alpha$ for *particle 2* is $w\sqrt{1 - u^2/c^2}$.

Why does these two particles have different vertical speeds? Shouldn't both vertical speeds be the same given that the vertical speeds are also the same for *Observer 1*?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Observer who observes more horizontal speed, observes less vertical speed. I mean  for two observers that are observing the same object, the observer that observes move horizontal speed, observes less vertical speed. I mean the observers have the same vertical speed and different horizontal speeds.

It is an effect called time dilation, although many people do not recognize that as time dilation. So let us say it like this: Horizontal speed causes a slowing down of vertical change of position.

Comment: Ok, so let me get this straight. Since *Observer 2* is moving with the horizontal velocity of *particle 1*, *Observer 2* sees a greater horizontal speed on *particle 2* because *particle 2*'s horizontal velocity is opposite and equal to *Observer 2*'s velocity. A greater relative horizontal velocity between *Observer 2* and *particle 1* provokes a greater effect on the relativity action on *particle 1*'s vertical velocity and thus the vertical velocity appear to slow down. Is that correct?

Comment: @ERP Yes, correct.